# Liked Text Box from Excel to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, powerpoint

I have a question about linking Excel Object to PowerPoint
If I copy a cell/graphs from Excel and paste special -> Paste Link -> Microsoft Excel Object into PowerPoint, in the PowerPoint file there will be hundreds of boxes and graphs that linked from Excel.

My question is if I want to change linked Excel file for all textbox and graphs, it will link from the exact same location, only difference file name. How can I do that?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the code on this page of the PPT FAQ I maintain:

https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm